# Problema con SSL al conectar a MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Cada vez que me conecto a la **Base de Datos** o intento ejecutar una consulta, me aparece el siguiente error en consola:

```
Sat Sep 10 17:38:48 BOT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

La siguiente es mi clase para conectarme y a la misma vez desconectarme a **MySQL**:

```
package comm.estudiante.dao.mysql;


import comm.estudiante.dao.mysql.interfaces.DBConnection;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MySQLDBConnection implements DBConnection {

String host = "localhost";
String port = "3306";
String db = "itla";
String table = "notas";
String user = "root";
String pass = "itla";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + db + "?user="
        + user + "&password=" + pass;
Connection con;
Statement stmnt;
ResultSet rs;

public Connection conectar() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
}

@Override
public void desconectar(Connection con) {
    if (con != null) {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

El problema dice que es de **SSL** pero no se como resolverlo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primero que nada, no es un error, **es una advertencia** (traducción de [WARN](https://translate.google.com/#en/es/warn)), por lo que no es algo vital para que tu aplicación deje de funcionar, pero sí es recomendable resolverla para ambientes como producción. Segundo, el mensaje te describe cómo resolverlo (énfasis mía):

> WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. **For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false**, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

Traducido a español (traducción y énfasis mías):

> ADVERTENCIA: No se recomienda establecer una conexión SSL sin la verificación de la identidad del servidor. De acuerdo a MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ y 5.7.6+, los requerimientos de conexión SSL deben ser establecidos por defecto si la opción no se coloca explícitamente. **Por conformidad con las aplicaciones existente que no utilizan SSL, la propiedad verifyServerCertificate (verificar el certificado del servidor) está puesta como 'false' (falso). Necesitas o bien deshabilitar SSL explícitamente con la configuración useSSL=false**, o colocar useSSL=true y proveer un almacén de confianza para la verificación del certificado del servidor.

En resumen, agrega la propiedad `useSSL=false` en tu cadena de conexión, en la parte final donde van los argumentos adicionales para la conexión de base de datos:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + db + "?user=" + user + "&password=" + pass + "&useSSL=false";
```

Fuera de esto, tu url de conexión a MySQL no debería tener los parámetros de usuario y contraseña, estos deberían pasar como parte del método `getConnection`. Adicional, el código que muestra la asignación de `String url` complica mucho su lectura y mantenimiento. Te ofrezco esta alternativa para mejorar la legibilidad:

```
//el puerto debe ser un número, no una cadena
//String port = "3306";
int port = 3306;

String url = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%d/%s?useSSL=false", host, port, db);

public Connection conectar() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, por el consejo @Luiggi, ciertamente mejora la legibilidad del código.